# Binary Search array of number strings not finding values

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, binary-search-tree

I know there are a ton of binary search examples, but I'm having difficulty getting any to work when I have a sorted array of numbered strings, for example.

```
const sortedStringNumbers = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"];
```

When I plug it into a binary search function like this:

```
function bsearch (Arr,value){
        var low  = 0 , high = Arr.length -1 ,mid ;      
        while (low <= high){
            mid = Math.floor((low+high)/2);     
            if(Arr[mid]==value) return true; 
            else if (Arr[mid]<value) low = mid+1;
            else high = mid-1;          
        }
        return -1 ;
    }
```

When I run:

`bsearch(sortedStringNumbers, '3')`

it returns `-1`

When I run :

`bsearch(sortedStringNumbers, '26)`

it returns true;

Lastly, the reason I simply don't convert the binary search input array is I need to use this function for two kinds of sorted arrays, the aforementioned kind, and others that contain words, such as: `const sortedWordsArray = ['Algebra', 'Biology', 'Chemistry', ...]`

The binary search array does work for word arrays, btw.

Comment: Your "sorted" numbers are not sorted. They're strings, so they need to be sorted *lexically*, not numerically.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure your array is sorted.

When you're making your comparison

```
Arr[mid]<value
```

or

```
Arr[mid]==value
```

They are being compared as strings rather than as numeric values.

If you'd like it to work in "both" scenarios, as you suggested, you could try something like this

```
function bsearch (Arr,value){
        var low  = 0 , high = Arr.length -1 ,mid ;      
        while (low <= high){
            mid = Math.floor((low+high)/2);     

            var int_val = Arr[mid];
            if (!isNaN(Arr[mid])) {
                int_val = parseInt(Arr[mid]);
            }

            if(int_val==value) { 
                return true; 
            }
            else if (int_val<value) {
                low = mid+1;
            }
            else {
                high = mid-1;          
            }
        }
        return -1 ;
}
```